# ESlint rule to avoid require

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

Is there any ESlint rule to force the developer to use `import` (ES6) instead of `require` (CommonJS)? Basically would like to show an error when someone is using require in our codebase.

I am using JavaScript and have my rules in a .eslintrc.json file.

Comment: Can you not use `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` and force modules?

Comment: You can use eslint-plugin-import with the no-commonjs rule

Comment: Rule: `no-var-requires`. 
Disallows the use of `require` statements except in import statements. In other words, the use of forms such as `var module = require("module")` are banned.